# adding a user to a webserver

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, webserver, user

How can I setup a user on my Ubuntu 10.04 VPS so I can login through FTP and upload .php .html, etc files. I know the default path is `/var/www` but I'd rather not login through root and upload to there, I'd like to have a separate user.

I've done `adduser NAME` but all that does is give them a directory in `/home` and allow SSH acces.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to transmit your passwords and files over an unencrypted connection instead of just using SFTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you rather use SFTP as it is more secure and modern protocol than the ancient FTP. SFTP uses the standard `ssh` port (22) and there are some great clients for it, notably [WinScp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: I understand that, but can't I have a separate user from `root` and still use SFTP?

Comment: Yes of course! Every user that you add to the machine (with `adduser`) can access it by default. You just have to be careful as to set the appropriate permissions.

Comment: Alright, well as I said, i've added a user but logging in through SFTP doesn't give me acces to actually uploading the files to be displayed, just gives me acces to the users directory in `/home`

Comment: There are several solutions to that. You can add the user to the group that the directory has (you can check via `ls -l /var`, then add the user to the group with `useradd -G {group-name} username`) or you can change the permissions of the `/var/www` directory altogether, so that anyone can write in it (not such a great idea if you have multiple users) by `chmod -R o+wr /var/www`